# Control Radio Buttons with a Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using a CMS that hides form elements behind tags, because of some system quirks I've had to set up a checkbox that controls the radio buttons so if the checkbox is ticked the "yes" radio button is selected if not the "no" is selected. I also want the radio buttons to have option "no" checked by default but I don't have control over the line of code for the radio buttons.

I found some Javascript that does a small part of this but I want to integrate it into the jQuery that displays and hides content when the box is ticked.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function() {
    $('#content1').toggle("slow");
});
```

The Javascript I have is this:

```
function ticked(){
    var ischecked = document.getElementById("checkbox").checked;
    var collection = document.getElementById("hideradio").getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    if(ischecked){collection[0].checked = true;}else{collection[0].checked = false;}
}
```

Can you please help write a version of the Javascript but integrate with my jQuery?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, I assume your html as like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" /> Check Box

<div id="content1" >
    Some Content <br />
    Some Content <br />
    Some Content <br />
    Some Content
</div>

<div id="hideradio">
    <input type="radio" name="rgroup" value="yes" /> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="rgroup" value="no" />  No
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){
     $('#hideradio input[type=radio][value=no]').attr('checked',true);
     $('#content1').hide();
});

$('#checkbox1').on('change', function() {
    $('#content1').toggle("slow");
    var self = this;
    if(self.checked)
        $('#hideradio input[type=radio][value=yes]').attr('checked',true);
    else
       $('#hideradio input[type=radio][value=no]').attr('checked',true);
});
```

A Quick **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ77s/1/)**

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to automatically have the "no" checked through the jQuery as well? The system I'm using disguises the <input> tags behind it's own generic tag so I don't have the option of choosing a checked=checked by default.

Comment: @Lee, check the updated answer, on dom ready, hide the content and make checked=checked for no radio.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't understand correctly then let me know.

I don't know your HTML code so I provide one

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test_ck" id="test_ck" />
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="test_radio" id="test_radio" />
</form>

<div id="content"> A content !!! </div>
```

and javascript jquery

```
$(function(){
    $("#test_ck").on("change", function(){
           $("#test_radio").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));               
        $("#content").toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Example -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wQxw/1/)

**UPDATED jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/6wQxw/2/

Comment: Fantastic! I just need it to automatically go to the second radio button "no" if the checkbox isn't ticked and when the page loads automatically. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

​

```
$(function(){
    $('#checkbox1').on('click' , function() {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if(isChecked){
           $('#radio1').attr('checked' , true);
            $('#content1').toggle("slow");
        }
        else{
            $('#radio1').attr('checked' , false);
        }
    });
});​
```

Check [[FIDDLE]](http://jsfiddle.net/tYXMh/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work - I got this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Have updated the code.. Also check the fiddle for a working demo

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29R7q/1/)

```
$(document).on('change', '#checkbox', function() { toggle(this); });

var toggle = function(obj) {
    var checked = $(obj || '#checkbox').is(':checked');
    $(':radio[value=no]').prop('checked', !checked);
    $(':radio[value=yes]').prop('checked', checked);
    $('#content').toggle(checked);
}

toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure JavaScript solution, no need to use jQuery:

```
<body>
<label for="a">Male</label>
<input type="radio" id="a">
<br/>
<label for="b">Female</label>
<input type="radio" id="b">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");// get elements
    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes); // convert nodes to array for use in forEach
    arr.forEach(function(obj){
        obj.addEventListener("change",function(e){
            arr.forEach(function(obj){
                obj.checked = false;//make other radio false
            });
            this.checked = true;// make this radio ture
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate your answers. You can either answer each question specifically focusing on the bits that differ, or flag the questions as duplicates and answer just once.